# C# LinqToSql SubmitChanges() does not update, even though PK is set

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
public int DeActivate(User entity) {
            try {
                using (UsersDataContext usersDC = new UsersDataContext()) {
                    users user = new users();
                    user = usersDC.users.Where(x => x.id == entity.Id).
                        Select(x => new users {active = x.active}).FirstOrDefault();
                    //user.active = entity.Active;
                    user.active = false;
                    usersDC.SubmitChanges();
                    return 1;
                    }
                }
            catch {
                return 0;
                }
        }
```

While running an NUnit test on the method, the method returns 1, as it is supposed to do, and while de-bugging no exceptions are thrown. But, when i cross check with the DB the records have not being affected.  I have tried the following: Re-created DBML file, checked for existance of PK, and checked the following sites:
[MSDN question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6165bce4-4651-427b-9f89-3d026060ef72/submitchanges-not-working?forum=linqprojectgeneral), [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231278/linq-to-sql-submit-changes-not-working), but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select statement is wrong. Try this.

```
public int DeActivate(User entity) {
   try {
     using (UsersDataContext usersDC = new UsersDataContext()) {
       var user = usersDC.users.Single(x => x.id == entity.Id);
       user.active = false;
       usersDC.SubmitChanges();
       return 1;
     }
    } catch {
      return 0;
    }
   }
```